# Make regex work with a closing bracket

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
$regex = '/(?:(?:\b(?:pp|[Ww]ars|[\.!?)]?\s*f|vs)[\.!?)]\s))\Z/mu';
```

It matches with:

```
$string = 'Wars! ';
```

But I want it to match with the following scenario:

```
$string = 'Wars!) ';
```

I have added the closing bracket there but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can add a `+` quantifier to the last `[.!?)]`: [`(?:(?:\b(?:pp|[Ww]ars|[.!?)]?\s*f|vs)[.!?)]+\s))\Z`](https://regex101.com/r/yK7nT9/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You got it! Thanks. Post as answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `*` quantifier to the last `[.!?)]` to match *zero or **more** occurrences*:

```
(?:(?:\b(?:pp|[Ww]ars|[.!?)]?\s*f|vs)[.!?)]*\s))\Z
                                           ^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK7nT9/3)

Also note that a `.` inside a character class does not have to be escaped to match a literal dot symbol.

Comment: Just one question, why doesn't this scenario work: https://regex101.com/r/yK7nT9/2 -- and what adjustment can I do to make it match with it?

Comment: I updated the answer: you actually  need a `*` quantifier (see  multiline regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK7nT9/4))